# MySQL stops in windows VM and shows innodb os error in logs(error no. 5)

Tags: mysql, innodb, windows, wamp

```
2020-08-23 17:22:36 5688 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-08-23 17:22:36 5688 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-08-23 17:22:36 5688 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-08-23 17:22:36 5688 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-08-23 17:22:36 5688 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2020-08-23 17:22:36 5688 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2020-08-23 17:22:36 5688 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-08-23 17:22:36 5688 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 32.0M
2020-08-23 17:22:36 5688 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-08-23 17:22:37 5688 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-08-23 17:22:37 5688 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1771332 and 1771332 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 24084333 in the ib_logfiles!
2020-08-23 17:22:37 5688 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2020-08-23 17:22:37 5688 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2020-08-23 17:22:37 5688 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2020-08-23 17:22:38 1640  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file table_a.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

I'm using VM and OS is Windows Server 2016 and Uniform Server.
If I set `innodb_force_recovery > 0`, nothing gets updated in db.
I have started mysql and apache as admin, also I have  tried deleting ib_logfile* and still nothing works.
In the other case, even if both mysql and apache are running, the web page shows like request can't be handled and these errors will be in mysql error log.
How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Akina: Log tells that *mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.* Adjust the access rights in server's filesystem for the account which is used for mysqld starting.